# Does the mean of two positive numbers obey these basic inequalities?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, ordered-fields

Suppose $a,b$ are positive real numbers. Does it follow that 
$$ a < \frac{a+b}{2} < b $$
provided $a < b$?

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $2a < a+b < 2b$, which is equivalent to $2a< a+b$ and $a+b < 2b$, which are both equivalent to $a<b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Multiplying each expression in the inequalities shows that) the statement is equivalent to
$$a + a < a + b < b + b,$$
and each of these inequalities follow from $a < b$.

Answer (score 1):

Mark two different numbers a and b such that $a<b$ on the real line and then compute arithmetic mean of two and observe where it lies.

Also if you reduce the above inequality into two $(a+b)/2> a$ and $(a+b)/2 < b$ and simplify it you would get $a<b$ which means your result holds good.